# Java Date Formatting DateFormat

Tags: java

Can we use `new DateFormat();` to create an object of `DateFormat`?

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
```

is used but can we use the following?

```
DateFormat df = new DateFormat(); 
df.getDateInstance();
```

Comment: No, because `DateFormat` is an abstract class and cannot be directly instantiated.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: By the way, these classes are now outmoded in Java 8 and later. Use the `java.time.format` package instead with the `java.time` types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateFormat is an abstract class, like all abstract classes you cannot instantiate them. You can only instantiate a subclass of an abstract class provided the subclass is not abstract also. To know more about abstract classes, look at [abstract classes tutorial by oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html)

Answer (score 4):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm.ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

[DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) is an abstract class with protected constructor.You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like this.
This statement won't even compile.

```
  DateFormat d=new DateFormat();
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is defined as

```
protected DateFormat()
```

which means you cannot call it like that.  Neither can you do something like:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat;
```

It does not provide any aliasing mechanism to avoid typing it. So you will have to always to do:

```
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
```

Or you can use a subclass as @Verhagen has pointed out.

It is also an abstract class, but one way you could do it is use an anonymous constructor:

```
    java.text.DateFormat df = new java.text.DateFormat(){
        @Override
        public Date parse(String source, ParsePosition pos) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public StringBuffer format(Date date, StringBuffer toAppendTo,
                FieldPosition fieldPosition) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    };
```

but in this case you have to define what those methods do.

Comment: Even if the constructor was `public`, the class is marked `abstract` so you couldn't invoke it using `new` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat which is an implementation and not an abstract class as stated in @Verhagen answer, but be bareful with it, most of the times you got to use it in a ThreadLocal to avoid those problems.

It has some pretty bad side effects when used in a multi threaded environment.

With Java 8 the recomended is to use the new Date API

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter =  
      DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormatPattern);  
   final String nowString = formatter.format(now8);
```